# x86 Assembly (YASM): Floating Point exception error

Tags: assembly, x86, yasm

I'm trying to compute the expression `i_sqrt=(((i_number/i_sqrt)+i_sqrt)/2)` where `i_number` is 78999999.

I have made my code in the ubuntu x86 `yasm` assembler but it throws the error described in the title. N is the number of iterations to perform; in my case is 50.

Could you help me to solve it or comment on where part of my code is the error or if I made some part somewhere wrong code.

Here is my code:

```
section .data
contador db 50  
i_number dq 78999999
i_sqrt dq 0
qAns1 dq 0
qAns2 dq 0
qAns3 dq 0

section .text
global _start

_start:
mov cl, byte[contador]

_ciclo:
;qAns1= i_number/i_sqrt
mov rax, qword [i_number]
cqo
idiv qword [i_sqrt]
mov qword [qAns1], rax
;qAns2= qAns1+i_sqrt
mov rax, qword [qAns1]
add rax, qword [i_sqrt]
mov qword [qAns2], rax
;qAns3=qAns2/2
mov rax, qword [qAns2]
cqo
mov rbx, 2
idiv rbx
mov qword [qAns3], rax
dec rcx
cmp rcx, 0
jne _ciclo

mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0 
syscall
```

**I have to match i_sqrt with i_number. How can I do this in my code?  Put i_sqrt equal to 0 only on initialization?** This is a solution, but how do I do it?

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you tell me where I have to verify

Answer (score 2):

`i_sqrt` is initialized to zero (`i_sqrt dq 0`) and not modified before you do `idiv qword [i_sqrt]`.  So you divide by zero.

Most Unix systems map the divide overflow exception to the SIGFPE signal, resulting in the confusing "floating point exception" message for an error that has nothing to do with floating point.  You just have to get used to this.

Comment: But then I have no solution?

Comment: I have to match i_sqrt with i_number, how can I do this in my code?
put i_sqrt equal to 0 only on initialization

Comment: But you use it (while it is still zero) before assigning a new value to it... I don't understand what result you expect for `i_sqrt=(((i_number/i_sqrt)+i_sqrt)/2)` with `i_sqrt` being zero... `(((78999999/0)+0)/2)` contains the term `78999999/0` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BOYNUGGET:  Well, what number *do* you want to divide by?

Comment: is that they tell me that i_sqrt = i_number how do I do this zero only use for initialization

Comment: If you want the initial value of `i_sqrt` to be `78999999`, same as `i_number`, then you should write `i_sqrt dq 78999999` instead of 0.